# How to get the "create statement" from FRM files in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I lost the ibd/ibdata files of my database, just get the FRM files.

So, How can I use the FRM file to recovery the database struct (just the feild name, create statement is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya need to read this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html

And cozy up to the hexdump of each frm

I will search around for a tool

The tool is called mysqlfrm and u can read about it here

http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.com/2013/04/mysql-utilities-new-frm-reader-utility.html?m=1

Format can be hex like mine or the new text version for frm's

Good luck